# Entity Framework for Oracle DB

Tags: entity-framework, odac

I am trying to use Entity Framework to connect to an Oracle Database, but when I right click -> add new Item -> "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" -> Generate from Database -> New Connection, I can not find the Oracle Provider in the provider list.

I have VS2012, the Database on a local machine, I installed ODAC 11g.

Comment: After you installed the ODAC, did you run the oraprovcfg.exe commands?

Comment: There's a few ways to install the ODAC / ODP.  There's an install that includes the Oracle Developer Tools and it includes the ODAC.  I believe that is hands off.  With just the ODAC, I remember having to run the oraprovcfg.exe like this: http://devblog.rayonnant.net/2011/04/oracle-11g-r2-x64-client-with-odac.html

Comment: I installed the latest ODAC 12c, and it worked out of the box. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest ODAC 12c provides that functionality.